# Is it possible remove chained navigation properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Lets say I have a Company table, a Department table, a Manager table, and an Employee table. There is a one to many relationship going down the list tables.  So the Employee table has a ManagerID foreign key, the Manager table a DepartmentID key, and so on.

I used the EF designer to create the DbContext, and the other classes. I added associations between the tables with the foreign keys in the designer.  The problem is I can't make associations between the Employee table and the Department or Company tables in the designer.

I tried creating a separate partial class for the Employee with the following Department property:

```
public Department Department {
    get { return this.Manager.Department; }
}
```

However, when I run the program I get the following exception:

*The specified type member 'Manager' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.*

I often query the Employee table, and then want to display the company and department information with the employee.  So there are many lines with `Employee.Manager.Department.Company.Field`, which makes it look cluttered.

Is it better to add a CompanyID to the Manager table and a CompanyID and DepartmentID to the Employee table or does that effect the database normalization? What sort of paradigms describe these problems?

Thoughts, opinions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

properties without setters completely ignored by EF so the exception you get is not relevant to those piece of code. your approach is fine and if you set up your entities correctly it will work.

Comment: I tried adding a setter `set {Order.Event = value;}`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: you wont add setter, first make your model working, other then that your code is correct